# Setting array equal to JSON array - Xcode

Tags: arrays, json, uitableview, httprequest, afnetworking

I'm trying to figure out how to populate a table from a JSON array. So far, I can populate my table cells perfectly fine by using the following code:

```
self.countries = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Argentina",@"China",@"Russia",nil];
```

Concerning the JSON, I can successfully retrieve one line of text at a time and display it in a label. My goal is to populate an entire table view from a JSON array. I tried using the following code, but it still won't populate my table. Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I searched everywhere and still can't figure it out:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://BlahBlahBlah.com/CountryList"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[JSON objectForKey:@"COUNTRIES"]);
    self.countries = [JSON objectForKey:@"COUNTRIES"];
}
failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

I am positive that the data is being retrieved, because the NSLog outputs the text perfectly fine. But when I try setting my array equal to the JSON array, nothing happens. I know the code is probably wrong, but I think I'm on the right track. Your help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
This is the text in the JSON file I'm using:

```
{
 "COUNTRIES": ["Argentina", "China", "Russia",]
}
```

-Miles

Comment: can you please show yoour json structure? is it something like array of dictionaries or so.? and try changing your array type NSArray to NSMutableArray.

Comment: @MicRO I posted the JSON structure above. I hope that's what you mean. NSMutableArray doesn't really do anything, but I really appreciate the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need some basic JSON parsing. If you only target iOS 5.0 and above devices, then you should use [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If you need to support earlier iOS versions, then I really recommend the open source [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) framework.

Having recommended the above, I myself almost always use the [Sensible TableView](http://sensiblecocoa.com) framework to fetch all data from my web service and automatically display it on a table view. Saves me a ton of manual labor and makes app maintenance a breeze, so it's probably something to consider too. Good luck!